# Build Angular Meteor app fails with angular-compilers 0.2.5

Tags: angular, meteor, angular-meteor, angular2-meteor

I use https://github.com/Urigo/angular-meteor/tree/master/atmosphere-packages/angular-compilers for my angular-meteor application. When i try compile with `meteor build` fails.

The command i run:

```
meteor build /my_directory_name --directory --server-only --architecture os.linux.x86_64
```

And when i run the application server bundle this error appears:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

My project use:

```
meteor-base@1.2.0
mobile-experience@1.0.5
mongo@1.3.0
reactive-var@1.0.11
jquery@1.11.10
tracker@1.1.3
standard-minifier-css@1.3.5
standard-minifier-js@2.2.0
es5-shim@4.6.15
shell-server@0.3.0
accounts-password@1.5.0
msavin:mongol
jalik:ufs
jalik:ufs-gridfs
service-configuration@1.0.11
accounts-ui@1.2.0
accounts-twitter@1.4.0
accounts-google@1.3.0
mys:fonts
check@1.2.5
email@1.2.3
astrocoders:one-signal
vsivsi:job-collection
btafel:accounts-facebook-cordova
babel-compiler@6.24.7
ecmascript@0.9.0
localstorage@1.2.0
percolate:synced-cron
meteorhacks:ssr
dynamic-import@0.2.0
angular-compilers
```

Angular-meteor:

```
angular-compilers@0.2.5
angular-html-compiler@0.2.5
angular-scss-compiler@0.2.5
angular-typescript-compiler@0.2.7_1
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "meteor --settings settings.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "1.0.0-beta.1",
    "@angular/animations": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@angular/common": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/core": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "2.0.0-beta.9",
    "@angular/forms": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/http": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-server": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/router": "4.4.6",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "8.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "2.0.0",
    "@types/node": "8.0.47",
    "angular-meteor": "1.3.12",
    "angular2-meteor-polyfills": "0.2.0",
    "angulartics2": "3.2.0",
    "babel-runtime": "6.26.0",
    "base-64": "0.1.0",
    "bcrypt": "^1.0.3",
    "core-js": "2.5.1",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "gm": "1.23.0",
    "google-material-color": "1.3.1",
    "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "jspdf": "1.3.5",
    "md5": "2.2.1",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "0.3.2",
    "meteor-rxjs": "0.4.8",
    "meteor-typings": "1.4.1",
    "microtime": "2.1.6",
    "ng2-page-scroll": "4.0.0-beta.12",
    "prismjs": "1.8.3",
    "qrious": "4.0.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "5.5.2",
    "spawn-sync": "1.0.15",
    "thread-sleep": "2.0.0",
    "try-thread-sleep": "1.0.2",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.2",
    "typescript": "2.5.3",
    "typescript-collections": "1.2.5",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "4.0.4",
    "@types/hammerjs": "2.0.35",
    "@types/highcharts": "5.0.9",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.6.2",
    "@types/meteor": "1.4.12",
    "@types/mocha": "2.2.44",
    "@types/prismjs": "1.6.5",
    "autoprefixer": "7.1.6",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.3",
    "chai": "4.1.2",
    "chai-spies": "0.7.1",
    "codelyzer": "3.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "node-sass": "4.5.3",
    "protractor": "5.2.0",
    "ts-node": "3.3.0",
    "tslint": "5.8.0"
  }
}
```

I appreciate the help. Regards!

Answer (score 0):

We've just released the new version of angular-compilers, and new version of compilers transpiles ES2015 import syntax into NodeJS's CommonJS Syntax. By these compilers, you need to use modules or ecmascript packages to make them work properly with updating your Meteor `meteor update --all-packages`.
You can see some working examples in `angular-meteor` GitHub repository.

Comment: I updated angular compilers to `angular-compilers@0.2.8_1,angular-html-compiler@0.2.8,angular-scss-compiler@0.2.8,angular-typescript-compiler@0.2.8_1` and the error continues

Comment: @LeonardoEspinosa could you add a small reproduction?

Comment: @Urigo The application server bundle fails if TranslateModule is included in app.module.ts. If is removed, works fine. I created example in   [link](https://github.com/leonardoespinosa/angular-compiler-test/tree/master). I try with different ngx-translate releases and error continues.

Comment: We've just release `angular-compilers@0.2.9` to address that

Answer (score 0):

The problem is Node doesnt support yet is6 imports ([here you have an article that explains it](https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/an-update-on-es6-modules-in-node-js-42c958b890c)) and produces the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import.`

When import the module ngx-translate (version 8.0.0) in the project, in the server bundle there is the file bundle/programs/server/packages/modules.js where it inserts the ngx-translate code in the following way:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { equals, isDefined } from './util';
import { TranslateService } from './translate.service';

var TranslateDirective = (function () {
    function TranslateDirective(translateService, element, _ref) {
        var _this = this;
        this.translateService = translateService;
        this.element = element;
        ......
        ......
```

And the imports in `bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/@ngx-translate/core/src` they are in the same way. That's the problem.

To solve problem with ngx-translate use release [9.0.0](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/releases/tag/v9.0.0) and the problem is solved.

But other npm modules present the same problem `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import` (the modules have to make a bundle for commonjs, isn't angular-meteor problem). You can solve this problem with babel like this way (for the example i use ngx-page-scroll that presenting the same problem):

In your project:

1. `npm install --save babel-cli babel-preset-es2015`
2. add a npm script in package.json in "scripts" scope

`"compile_ngx-page-scroll": "babel node_modules/ngx-page-scroll -d node_modules/ngx-page-scroll --presets es2015"`

3. run `npm install` to install the dependencies
4. run `npm run compile_ngx-page-scroll` and babel will compile the targeted js files
5. run your server and should work